# Call a javascript function from select element in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function Myfunc(obj1)
{
  alert(obj1.prop('outerHTML'));
}
```

```html
 <select id="myselect" onchange="MyFunc(jQuery(this))">
                     <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
                     <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
                     <option value="v3" selected="selected">Value 3</option>
 </select>
```

I have the above two snippets.
When i do alert of the object i get the complete <select&tg; tag along with all it's options.

But, What i want is the object passed should only just be the option which i have selected and not the complete select element block.

Comment: yes i wanted the complete HTML of the option selected, and i am really thankful to @Regent for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of outdated `onchange` you can use jQuery `$('selector').change(function() { });`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufnsv3te/).

Simplified HTML:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="v3" selected="selected">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myselect').change(function()
    {
        alert($(this).find(':selected').text());
    });
});
```

**Update**. If you need selected `<option>` outer HTML, then it can be:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufnsv3te/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myselect').change(function()
    {
        alert($(this).find(':selected')[0].outerHTML);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for advise to use unobtrusive event handlers but -1 for not reading the question. It was the option element he wanted, not the text.

Comment: @anddoutoi are you sure `<option value="v1">Value 1</option>` is requested, not only its text value? I actually read question.

Comment: "But, What i want is the object passed should only just be the option which i have selected"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`onchange="MyFunc(jQuery(this).find('option:selected'))`"

Comment: Why are you recommending inline JavaScript? Separate your concerns and put them in a separate JS file.

Comment: Just answered the question as is. But absolutely agree with f.e. Regent's solution as a better approach of handling events.

Comment: @jevgenig yes, I agree, that it is "as is", and this answer is voted up, by the way. But it's good to show OP appropriate way to handle events. That is the mentioned idea.

Comment: With that philosophy we should teach OP to attach the listener onDOMReady or window.onload and perhaps even wrap it in AMD or a CommonJS module and sprinkle it with some architectural advise? Question is: how far is to far?

Comment: @Regent yes, I agree, that it is "good to show OP appropriate way to handle events". Same as "console.debug(...)" is a good replace for alert, and "debugger;" is the best approach to experiment with things.

Answer (score 1):

Use as

```
function MyFunc(obj1)
{
    alert($("#myselect option:selected").text());
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/959vm8f5/)

OR You can use

```
function MyFunc(obj1)
{
    alert($("#myselect option:selected").html());
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/959vm8f5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector) selector follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myselect').on('change', function() {
        alert($(this).find('option:selected').eq(0));
    });
});
```

Comment: OP wants the option element. Not the value. Read the Q before submitting the A.

Comment: @SwaghettiYolonese why `.eq(0)`?

Comment: Somehow I can't undo my downvote and make a upvote. Says it need to be edited first >.<

Comment: @TJ just to make sure it matches what we need. I can't explain why I always use eq(0) even when I'm sure I catch 1 element. As far as I remember I had some problems in the past while I didn't do it this way.

Comment: @anddoutoi No problem I'm here to learn and help not for points.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass object or you can fetch selected option in function.

To get selected option html in function use below code -

**NOTE** - please correct spelling of function either in `onchange` or function declaration.

```js
function MyFunc(obj1)
{
  var value = obj1.value;
  var optionHTML = $(obj1).find('option[value="'+value+'"]');
  
  alert($('<div>').append(optionHTML.clone()).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" onchange="MyFunc(this)">
      <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="v3" selected="selected">Value 3</option>
 </select>
```

Another way is to bind `change` event handler using jquery and get the option html

```js
$('#myselect').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var option = $(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]');
  var optionHTML = $('<div>').append(option.clone()).html();
  alert(optionHTML);
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
<select id="myselect">
     <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
     <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
     <option value="v3" selected="selected">Value 3</option>
</select>
```